# How to take the data from the angular2 firebase data.?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have candidates_list table in angular2 firebase, but I am not getting the value from it.

My ts file is this

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { FirebseService } from "app/firebse.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidate-reg-complete',
  templateUrl: './candidate-reg-complete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidate-reg-complete.component.css']
})
export class CandidateRegCompleteComponent implements OnInit {
  content:any;
item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,
  private firebaseService:FirebseService) { 
    this.item = db.object('candidates_list');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  upload(documents){

  //  let file=user.files[0];
  //   console.log(file);
  //  console.log(file.name);
  let storageRef=firebase.storage().ref();

    for(let selectedFile of[(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('file')).files[0]]){

     let path='/resumes/'+selectedFile.name;
      let iRef=storageRef.child(path);
      iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot)=>{
        debugger;
       documents.resume=selectedFile.name;
       documents.path=path;

        var Userid=localStorage.getItem('user');
        console.log(documents);
        let content=this.db.object('/candidates_list/'+Userid);
        console.log(content);

        // this.db.object('/candidates_list/'+Userid).update(documents);
      localStorage.setItem('resume',documents.path);

      })
 }

}
}
```

The problem is with this code

```
 let content=this.db.object('/candidates_list/'+Userid);
 console.log(content);
```

When I try to console this value, the output is like this..

```
FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: U, source: FirebaseObjectObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
```

Not conoling the exact content, so any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the observable. Try this:

```
 let content = this.db.object('/candidates_list/'+Userid)
  content.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)})
```

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark as solved if happy. Cheers.